# Adding new ARM machine to Qemu

Tags: embedded, qemu, buildroot

I've used `buildroot` to compile a firmware targetting the `LPC EA3250` board, I'm trying to get this to run using qemu so that I can test changes to the firmware on my machine. I've tried commands such as:

```
 qemu-system-arm -M virt -kernel uImage -hda rootfs.ext2 -boot c -m 128M -append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0,38400n8"
```

But I keep getting similar errors no matter which `-M` option I apply. It seems that somehow I need to get a new machine option to pass qemu which will correspond to my board. I've found [this config file](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded/blob/master/conf/machine/ea3250.conf) which seems to be the configuration needed for the board I'm looking at.

What I would like to know is how to insert this config into `qemu`. Do I have to place this config somewhere and then recompile everything? If I do where do I need to put it?

Answer (score 2):

On further investigation it seems that the config file I found is for something else entirely. The LPC EA3250 is not supported by qemu and adding in support for additional machines is an extensive task.